# How to deal with being contacted by a company after I didn't pass their interview process before?

Tags: reinterviewing

Yesterday I posted a question wether 2 months was a normal time for an interview process. I got my answer today, and they told me they "wouldn't move forward with my application for this, but they will notify me of future opportunities".

I didn't ask for the reasons why I was declined because, frankly, I didn't care. Assuming the "future opportunities" is not just politeness and they do contact me in the future, **what would be the correct way to answer?**

For this position we didn't even get to the stage of discussing salary. **Would it be impolite if I answered asking for their offering before moving forward with any more "interviews"?** In case they don't have a tangible monetary offering, I'm not interested in wasting any more time with them in interviews. I get the feeling that their answer would be that the offering would depend on "the result of the interview", which, like I said, I won't be interested in taking if there isn't a real offer.

Comment: Did the original posting that you applied for have salary information?

Comment: @sf02 no, it didn't.

Comment: I don't think the answers to your actual question will really have anything to do with the fact that you've interviewed there before. If you have strict salary requirements, it probably makes sense to behave the same way regardless of if you've interviewed at a specific company before or not.

Answer (score 5):

> Would it be impolite if I answered asking for their offering before moving forward with any more "interviews"?

There is nothing wrong with asking for the position's salary although there is no need to explicitly state that you need to know it before moving forward.

You can say something like:

> Hello X, thank you for reaching out to me.  Could you please provide the job description and salary information for this position?

Give the company an opportunity to answer your question.  At the very least they should provide a lower and upper range.  If they refuse, then thank them for their time and move on to your next opportunity.  The lack of transparency on salary is a big red flag.

Comment: how would you word such an answer in a formal email?

Comment: @hjf Edited answer to include that

Answer (score 3):

This experience you've had?  This is normal.  What they mean when hey say they "wouldn't move forward with my application for this, but they will notify me of future opportunities" is that they don't want you for the current position, but they don't find you fundamentally objectionable, and will keep your resume on file.  That, and the fact that they actually contacted you back afterwards is actually more polite than normal.  Generally, companies that decide not to take you default to just never contacting you again.  The amount of time it took to go through the interview process was long, but that's most likely more about them being busy and/or disorganized than anything deliberate or malicious.

Pay is always one of the last things decided.  No one is going to tell you how much they're going to pay you before they even know if they want you in the first place.  The "real offer" you're talking about here is something that happens at the end of the interview process, rather than the beginning.

Now, they've indicated to you that their interview process is super-long, and may or may not come to anything.  If you find that seriously annoying, you might not want to bother interviewing with them again... but the only way in which they're any way exceptional is the time it took to get through it.  This is why you should keep looking for other places even once interviews at one place have started.

Comment: The problem is that not even a salary range was proposed. Also their process was long due to them being "busy", one of the interviewers was remote with only audio and no video, the test was done in pen and paper (software developer). When i asked about schedules they said they're "flexible". They looked a bit more messy and amateurish than a "flexible and cool place to work". All of which I don't mind as long as the money is good...

Comment: @hjf the question of "how do I get a company to admit to anything resembling a salary range" is a distinct and uglier one.  If that's the core of your question, then the question should be asked like that, and there's a lot of Q/A on that already.  It's not pretty.

Answer (score 0):

> For this position we didn't even get to the stage of discussing
>   salary. Would it be impolite if I answered asking for their offering
>   before moving forward with any more "interviews"?

Since they didn't discuss salary up front during your first go-round, it's unlikely they would do so the second time.

Asking for that will likely elicit a reply along the lines of "Let's no get ahead of ourselves here. We can talk about salary if we get to the point where we both think this is a good fit."

If you do happen to get called back for an interview for a future opportunity, take it as a positive sign, since they already know more about you than they did before your first set of interviews.

Answer (score 0):

> In case they don't have a tangible monetary offering, I'm not interested in wasting any more time with them in interviews.

You don't want to waste time, but they don't want to, either.  There are some companies who are forced by bureaucracy to interview multiple candidates even though they already know who they want to hire. This is rare, however.  No one wants to go through interviews for no good reason. And they definitely won't call you back a second time for that.  If they call you back it will be for a real position.

Most positions have a normal range of salaries, and I was always told to put "open" under salary requirements.  **It isn't impolite to ask for salary ranges, but it is potentially one more thing that they might use to eliminate you.**  Some positions really want people who are motivated by money (sales jobs are this way), but some companies like to pretend that everyone works there for the fun times they have.  My advice is don't take the initial rejection personally.  I have hired people who were turned down previously, because jobs and requirements change.